# Azure VM SQL Server Automated Backup doing log backups only

Tags: sql-server-2019, azure, azure-vm, azure-blob-storage

We have an Azure VM running our own copy of SQL Server 2019, and we have just configured the Automated Backup functionality.

I have it configured like this:

[image: Automated Backup configuration]

Everything seems to be fine, except for the fact that we do not seem to be getting any full backups. I have checked our storage account in the backup container, and we have all the expected logs for each user database, but no trace of any full backups.

Configuration seems pretty straightforward, so I can't see anything wrong here. I have also checked various logs on the VM for both Windows and SQL Server itself, and I can see the log backups from the Automated Backup happening, but no reference to full backups or any errors or warnings that might indicate something is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there log backups at 1 AM?...Are you sure the server is online / *awake* at 1 AM?

Comment: Have you queried msdb.dbo.backupset to see if the backups are being performed?